# Altering hdfs replication factor dynamically in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs, replication-factor

In a Spark (3.2.0) application, i need to change the replication factor for different files written to HDFS. For instance, i write some temporary files, and i want them to be written with a replication factor 1. Then, i write some files that are going to be persistent, and i want them to be written with a replication factor 2, sometimes 3.

However, as i tested; `dfs.replication` in `SparkContext.hadoopConfiguration` does not affect the replication factor of the file at all, whilst `spark.hadoop.dfs.replication` sets it (or changes the default replication that is set in HDFS side) only when the `SparkSession` is created with a previously defined `SparkConf` as below.

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.hadoop.dfs.replication", "1")) // works but cannot be changed later.
val sparkSession: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.config(conf).getOrCreate()
```

Having made some search on the documentation, i came across with the configuration `spark.sql.legacy.setCommandRejectsSparkCoreConfs` that is added to core conf in Spark 3.0, and by default is set to `true`, and to change some other core confs it is needed to be set to `false` explicitly while the `SparkSession` is created. Even if i did that and prevent the errors like `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot modify the value of a Spark config`, setting replication factor to a different value by setting both configs in a function like below

```
def setReplicationFactor(rf: Short): Unit = {
      val activeSparkSession = SparkSession.getActiveSession.get
      activeSparkSession.conf.set("spark.hadoop.dfs.replication", rf.toString)
      activeSparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("dfs.replication", rf.toString)
}
```

does not change the files being written with the updated `SparkConf` and `SparkContext.hadoopConfiguration`.

Is there any way to achieve writing files to HDFS with different replication factors within the same spark session?

Answer (score 0):

Totally can be done on a per file/folder basis.  But you need to use hadoop tools.

Rest Call:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html

There are also command-line options but I think the WebHDFS is cleaner.

Comment: I think OP's question is about Spark/programmatic way of doing it.